# Retornar array de inteiros, exceto os 0. Como faço?

Tags: java, array

O método recebe dois números por parâmetro, e devolve um *array* com os números ímpares entre esses dois números.

```
public static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    int odd[] = new int[r];
    for(int i=0; i<odd.length;i++){
        if(l<=r && l%2!=0){
            odd[i]=l;
        } l++; 
    }
        return odd;
}
```

Porém, está retornando os números zeros no *array*, e é para retornar apenas os ímpares.

No momento, se colocar `oddNumbers(2,5)`, o resultado irá ser: `0 3 0 5 0`

Como faço para retornar apenas as posições preenchidas? `3 5`

Comment: Sim, porque um array inteiro é iniciado com todos os campos como 0. Os que você não preenche continuam com esse valor.

Comment: Sim, sim. Mas há alguma maneira de retornar apenas os campos preenchidos?

Comment: Criando um array somente com a quantidade de valores que precisa retornar ou utilizando ArrayList.

Comment: Você quer retornar um *array* que retorne os ímpares entre `l` e `r`, é isso?

Comment: @Daniel preenchidos com que?

Comment: @bigown Exato, um array que retorne os ímpares entre l e r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa criar um *array* que caiba todos os elementos gerados, pode fazer um só com a quantidade de elementos finais. Mais ainda não precisa filtrar nada, pode usar matemática para saber de antemão quais são os ímpares. Não fiz validações necessárias. Dá até para simplificar mais, mas para não complicar demais para iniciantes é isto:

```
class HelloWord {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int i : oddNumbers(2, 5)) System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static int[] oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
        l += 1 - l % 2;
        r -= 1 - r % 2;
        int odd[] = new int[(r - l) / 2 + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < odd.length; i++) odd[i] = l + (i * 2);
        return odd;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/GThtpg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kzbehtjj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/FillOdd.java).

Comment: Está funcionando perfeitamente! Muito obrigado mesmo!